# Functions where the product rule doesn't hold

Tags: analysis

I've got the following problem

Find two right continuous functions $F,G: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}  $ of bounded variation such that the usual product rule doesn't hold, that is
$ \int_{(a,b]} G(x)dF(x) = F(b)G(b)-F(a)G(a)- \int_{(a,b]} F(x)dG(x) $
is not true.

I thougth of taking functions where the points of discontinuity are the same, but then the integral doesn't exist at all. Is there another way than just trying?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of taking a common point of discontinuity was correct.  For example take $a=0$ and $b=1$ and let $F(x)=G(x)=I_{(0,\frac{1}{2}]}(x)$ where $I$ is the indicator function.  You then have $dF(x)=dG(x)=-\delta_\frac{1}{2}(dx)$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta.  Thus $\int_0^1 F(x)dG(x) = -F(\frac{1}{2}) = -1 = \int_0^1 G(x)dF(x)$ so the product rule formula suggests $-1 = 0 - 1 +1$, which is false as you require.

If you change $F$ just at the point $\frac{1}{2}$ by setting $F(x)=I_{(0,\frac{1}{2})}(x)$ (the end point is no longer in the interval), then the product rule formula works again.  This is part of a more general result for BV functions, you can find much more information in the book "Functions of bounded variation and free discontinuity problems" by Ambrosio et al.; start with Theorem 3.96 and Example 3.97.